# Find the angle, slope and intercept of a line within R

Tags: r, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the angle, slope and intercept of line 3 which is 60 degrees or `pi/3` away from line 1. I know that information for the other lines.

[image]

```
x1 = 652 
x2 = 1017 
y1 = 194
y2 = 632

## Line 1 information 
angle.l1 = 1.565595
slope.l1 = 1.2
intercept.l1 = -588.4

## Line 2 information
angle.l2 = 0.5183978
slope.l2 = 0.5704363
intercept.l2 = 51.8663
```

I would like to save the results as `angle.l3`, `slope.l3` and `intercept.l3`

Comment: Isn't angle.l3 = angle.l1 + pi/3 ?   Isn't slope.l3 = tan(angle.l3) ?  You have a point and the slope,   solve for the intercept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you conclude that `angle.l1 = 1.565595`?

```
## "line1" passes (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)
slope.l1 <- (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
#[1] 1.2
angle.l1 <- atan(slope.l1)
#[1] 0.8760581
```

Also, how did you conclude that the angle between "line3" and "line1" is `pi / 3`? If so, since "line3" has a bigger angle with x-axis than "line1" with x-axis, then:

```
angle.l3 <- angle.l1 + pi / 3
#[1] 1.923256
slope.l3 <- tan(angle.l3)
#[1] -2.718736
```

You get a negative slope for "line3" which can't be right according to your figure.

---

Fortunately you get the information for "line2" correct.

```
angle.l2 <- 0.5183978
slope.l2 <- 0.5704363
intercept.l2 <- 51.8663
```

Do you mean to say that the angle between "line2" and "line3" is `pi / 3`? If so,

```
angle.l3 <- angle.l2 + pi / 3
#[1] 1.923256
angle.l3 * 180 / pi
#[1] 89.70201
```

which is saying that "line3" is nearly 90 degree from x-axis, which does not look true from your graph.

---

What is the relationship between "line1", "line2" and "line3"? This is a critical piece of information that you didn't mention. If "line3" is a reflection of "line2" around "line1", then the solution is easy:

```
angle.l3 <- angle.l1 + (angle.l1 - angle.l2)
#[1] 1.233718
angle.l3 * 180 / pi
#[1] 70.68685
```

Em, 70.68 degree is looking sensible. So:

```
slope.l3 <- tan(angle.l3)
#[1] 2.853452

# "line3" passes (0, intercept.l3) and (x2, y2)
intercept.l3 <- y2 - slope.l3 * x2
#[1] -2269.961
```